Aligning Grid elements by symbol for "equals" and symbol for "approximately equals"
The following code aligns the elements of a grid by the symbol "=".
  Grid[{{"2pi+y = 7"}, {"y = 7-2pi"},
  {"y \[TildeTilde] 0.716815"}}, Alignment -> "="]

The output is

Looks good!  Now, I would like the third row to also align by the symbol "$\approx$".  In other words, I would like the option Alignment (in the code above) to be set to something like
Alignment -> "=" or "$\approx$"
Of course, this setting does not work, but I am hoping there is away to do it. Do you have any ideas?
I need a general solution, as I will placing this code in my stylesheet for all grids. Right now, I have the following in my stylesheet for Notebook options.
GridBoxOptions -> {
   GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> "="}}

It works for aligning by "=" but I need it to also work for "$\approx$".
Edit: Also, I would like to do this without using alignment markers.

I have two possible solutions:

Grid allows you to specify different alignments for each cell.

data = {{"2pi+y = 7"}, {"y = 7-2pi"}, {"y ≈ 0.716815"}};

alignedGrid[data_, strs_, opts___] := 
 Grid[data, 
  Alignment -> {Center, Automatic, 
    First /@ MapIndexed[#2 -> First@StringCases[#1, strs] &, data, {2}]}, opts]

alignedGrid[data, "=" | "≈"]


Insert some invisible character, like \[InvisibleSpace], before your equal symbols.

alignedGrid[data_, strs_, opts___] := 
 Grid[Map[StringReplace[s : (strs) :> "\[InvisibleSpace]" <> s], 
   data, {-1}], Alignment -> "\[InvisibleSpace]", opts]

alignedGrid[data, "=" | "≈"]


